# Set object properties through a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have very little experience with Object Oriented Programming specially in Python. I have two classes:

```
def set_other_values(data):
   self.apple = "data"

class Something(Else):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super.__init__(**kwargs)
       self.apple = ''
       self.mango = ''

   def something_function(self):
       // Python Code

class Anything(Something):
   def construct(self):
       self.mango = "10 Mangoes"
       set_other_values(data)  
       self.something_function()
```

From my understanding, when `Anything` is instantiated, it calls `__init()__` from `Something` first. The variables are then initialized inside the constructor of `Anything` and we can also call some parent functions there.

There are many more classes like `Anything` where the values of class properties will be set by dynamic data. I defined a function called `set_other_variables()` to set the value of all those properties. However, I keep getting error about undefined `self`.

Where and how should I define by function `set_other_values()` so that it sets values for all classes without any errors about `self`?

I tried to define it in `Something` and then call it from `Anything` like:

```
class Something(Else):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super.__init__(**kwargs)
       self.apple = ''
       self.mango = ''

   def something_function(self):
       // Python Code

   
   def set_other_values(data):
      self.apple = "data"

class Anything(Something):
   def construct(self):
       self.mango = "10 Mangoes"
       self.set_other_values(data)   
       self.something_function()
```

However, I got the error about `1 positional argument but 2 were given` for `set_other_values()`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have valid Python syntax. Be aware that "From my understanding, when Anything is instantiated, it calls __init()__ from Something first." is wrong – like any other method, ``__init__`` must explicitly call its parent implementation (e.g. via ``super().__init__``) if desired.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi did you mean changing `Class` to `class`? Thanks. :)

Comment: I also mean comments, and potentially other things I stopped checking after hitting the second syntax error.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Did you run the code somewhere?

Comment: The syntax highlighter already showed some (the ``Class`` typo). But yes, formulating an answer usually involves showing valid code based on the question code – so running it comes as a given.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Hehe. Sorry. I guess it created problems because `Else` is not defined anywhere. I tried to write pseudocode to explain the problem I am facing. I can't post the whole code because it is thousand of lines and there are a lot of classes involved.

Comment: I just wanted information about placing `set_other_values()` at a location where it won't cause errors.

Comment: Without working code, it is impossible to say *where* and *why* you are getting errors in the first place. You *likely* already get an error from the misconception about not having to call the parent ``__init__`` (and taking its arguments as well), but that is a guess.

Comment: There are no errors anywhere in the code if I set the value of all properties inside `construct`. The only thing that causes the error is when I try to move the assignment code into a function to avoid duplication.

Comment: Well, as shown ``set_other_values`` does not take a ``self`` parameter. It should, though.

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi. :) That's what I tried just a few moments ago and it worked. I was about to post that as an answer when you commented.

Previously, I thought that `self` cannot be passed to an outside function because it is part of the class itself.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Could you please recommend any resources where I can learn all these basics of OOP in Python?

Comment: You define `set_other_values` and try to use the variable `self`, but *that isn't defined anywhere in that scope*. `self` is just a convetional name given to the *first argument* of a function that is used as a method in a class. When that method is called on an instance of the class, it is implicitly passed the instance as the first argument. If you want to use a function from outside the class, you have to manually call that function and pass it the instance explicitly. You can think of `my_instance.method()` as `MyClass.method(my_instance)`, although it doesn't work exactly like that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @juanpa.arrivillaga :)

Answer (score -2):

you should use setattr this way you prevent that you program get stopped

```
def set_atrributes(self, **kwargs):
    for key in kwargs:
        if hasattr(self, key):
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
```